# Unable to connect to AWS Redis endpoint using redis-cli. Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I created `cache.t2.small` Redis under ElastiCache. It's available.

I have the endpoint: `portal-test.abcdef.ab.0001.abcd1.cache.amazonaws.com`.

I `ssh`'ed to the instance (tried via `ubuntu@ip-172-xx-xx-xx` and `runcloud@ip-172-xx-xx-xx`). I'm trying to connect via `redis-cli` by typing:

> redis-cli -h portal-test.abcdef.ab.0001.abcd1.cache.amazonaws.com
>   -p 6379 ping

I expect `PONG` but instead I get

> Could not connect to Redis at
>   portal-test.abcdef.ab.0001.abcd1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379:
>   **Connection timed out**

I went into my EC2 instance and defined the inbound traffic for port `6379`:

[image]

On runcloud (that I used for this instance) I also opened the port and successfully deployed the firewall rules:

[image]

Same timeout. What am I missing?

Comment: Just a suggestion, outbound rules allow all traffic?

Comment: Did you set it to open to public access on your Elasticache end? (You are only showing your ec2 inbound security group)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found the solution.

**Culprit:**

> Redis I created **was not in the same VPC / Availability Zone / Subnet
>   as the EC2** instance where my Laravel app lives. First one had IP 10.x.x.x > while the EC2 instance was 172.x.x.x. I assume this mismatch was preventing
>   both ends to talk to each other.

**Solution:**

When you create Redis, simply **assign it to the same VPC as your existing EC2 instance where your Laravel baby lives**. Also **reuse** the same security group where you open port 6379 (assuming you picked this port as a default one when creating your Redis).

Now SSH into you EC2 and from within type:

```
redis-cli -h endpoint-from-your-aws-redis-dashboard -p 6379 ping
```

If you get:

> **PONG**

you're the winner.

Comment: Perfect, this helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: what is Laravel "baby"?

Comment: Your Laravel project…

Comment: This was killing me... I had all of the above and still no joy. I found that I had to allow the **private** IPv4 NOT the public of the EC2 instance in the sec group for redis. Also bear in mind that serverless clusters must use TLS, so if you're using a `redis-cli` client that is compiled without TLS support, dead end.

Answer (score 3):

Matt's answer lead me in the right direction. However, a small adjustment made my connection work. I looked over the security groups and I noticed that the security group that I had open connections to (i.e.`Custom TCP 6379`) wasn't bound to my ElastiCache Redis instance.

To modify your security groups in your ElastiCache Instance:

- Click on your instance (make sure its highlighted)
- Click on the Actions Dropdown Menu
- Modify
- VPC Security Groups (click on pencil icon)
- Select Security Groups & Save
- Finally, click on **Modify**

Wait until your ElastiCache Instance is done modifying then ssh into your EC2 Instance. Finally, try Matt's `ping` `pong` method.

Hope it helps!